# UITextField border for right side only in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

In my swift project, I want to add right side border only for my textfield, because, I have two textfields in single tableviewcell, so, I want to show them as separated with border of right side for first textfield.

Any suggestions, thanks!!

Comment: can i say something? why can't you add the rightview for textfield :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this method for textfield

```
let border = CALayer()
let height = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: searchField.frame.size.width - height, y: 0, width:  searchField.frame.size.width, height: searchField.frame.size.height)

border.borderWidth = height
searchField.layer.addSublayer(border)
searchField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Below is the outcome of the code above

[image: outcome of the code above]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This.**

```
CGFloat width = 5;
UIView *bottomBorder = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.textField1.frame.size.width - width,0,width,_textField1.frame.size.height)];
[bottomBorder setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[_textField1 addSubview:bottomBorder];
```

[image: Look Like This]

Answer (score 0):

Choice is yours,

**Way 1:** Create IBDesignable & assign it to textfield in class attribute,

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class IBDesignableTextField: UITextField {


    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let border = CALayer()
        let height = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - height, y: 0, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

        border.borderWidth = height
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }


}
```

**Way 2:** @Dixit Akabari explained

**Way 3:** You can simply add right view to textfield as a your border image